# D3 Force Graph Neighboring Without Index (Including Self)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

I am basing my D3 Force Model after [this example: H is for Highlights.](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/) My JSON data is formatted differently since it uses the id as target/source instead of the default index given as a node property.

Sample of my JSON:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "foo","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"grabbable": true,"grabbed":false},
    {"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "bar","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"grabbable": true}
],
"links": [
    {classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue"","source":"foo","target":"bar","visible":true},"grabbable":false},
    {classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue"","source":"bar","target":"foo","visible":true},"grabbable":false}
]
}
```

So as you can see I have both the target/source within the data and it uses the id as the type. Now here I am having trouble getting the highlight to work. I have it where it highlights its neighboring nodes and links BUT for some reason it doesn't keep the node itself highlighted. I have added arrows below to what I think needs modification but I am not sure what the issue is at all.

```
    // sets the source and target to use id instead of index
    var edges = [];
    root.links.forEach(function(e) {
        var sourceNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                    return n.data.id === e.data.source;
                })[0],
                targetNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                    return n.data.id === e.data.target;
                })[0];

        edges.push({
            source: sourceNode,
            target: targetNode
        });
    });


    // Create an array logging what is connected to what
    var linkedByIndex = { };


    // array algorithm for what is connected to what
    for (var i = 0; i < root.nodes.length; i++) {
        linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
    };
    root.links.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.data.source + "," + d.data.target] = 1;
    });


    // This function looks up whether a pair are neighbors
    function neighboring(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.data.id + "," + b.data.id]; <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }


    function connectedNodes() {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighboring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });

        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index| d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
    }
```

I have played around with it and I am not sure what is wrong with my algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Add the following line which modifies the node selected to the end of the connected node function

Code added

```
return d3.select(this).style("opacity",1);
```

So now it looks like...

```
function connectedNodes() {

        // Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        // Ternary operator. condition | condition ? value if true : value if false
        // the | means or
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;

        });

        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });

        // Maintains opacity of selected node.
        return d3.select(this).style("opacity",1);
}
```